# Why LinkedIn inFollow button script not generating button when run locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, linkedin-api

I copied the code from [this link](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company) by giving company name and clicking the Get Code button. It generated the code given below

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="361557" data-counter="right"></script>
```

I created an HTML file with these scipts to create an **inFollow** button. But when I run that HTML file locally, it shws me a blank page instead of an **inFollow** button. But when the same HTML file I deployed in a server and run it, the output is as expected, I mean it shows me the **inFollow** button.

So my question is why the script given by the **LinkedIn dev** site is not able to generate **inFollow** button when run locally. What should I change that script to get the button when run locally.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**See first , run the project in chrome open the inspect element and save the linkedin logo image to your desktop.**

**Now in the //platform.linkedin.com/in.js file give the path of image locally that has been saved by you on the desktop or from desktop now to your project's image folder.**

**One more option could be....
If you have saved the in.js file locally then check the image path in it and save to the image path on server. to get the image path on server again use inspect element of chrome. or developers toolbar of your mozilla firefox browser.
**

If this doesn't work then let me know!